# MS SQL Server Создать Job

Tags: sql, sql-server

1. Есть два сервера с установленным MS SQL Server Developer.
2. На первом сервере развернута основная база данных, на втором - хранилище.
   Предполагается, что экземпляров основной базы данных может быть несколько.

Что необходимо: перенести данные из основной базы в хранилище.
Что хочется: создать Job, который будет переносить данные.

Нашёл, как обращаться к другому серверу, но в моей таблице sys.servers сервер один.
Вопрос: есть ли в принципе такая возможность переноса данных, или нужно это делать кодом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно прилинковать все сервера к которым вы собираетесь обращаться.
Есть два способа создания связанного сервера:

**Через UI SSMS**

Здесь все сводится к тому что надо открыть SSMS, найти в обозревателе объектов пункт *Linked Servers*, и заполнять поля следуя инструкции из статьи ниже.

Подробнее: [How to create and configure a linked server in SQL Server Management Studio](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-create-and-configure-a-linked-server-in-sql-server-management-studio/)

**Скриптами**

1) Пример скрипта для создания свзянного сервера с экземпляром `SRVTEST\SQLTEST`.

```
USE [master]  
GO  
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver   
    @server = N'SRVTEST\SQLTEST',   
    @srvproduct=N'SQL Server' ;  
GO
```

2) Дальше если вы используюте виндовую авторизацию вам необходимо прокинуть логин входа на связанный сервер

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin   
    @rmtsrvname = N'SRVTEST\SQLTEST',   
    @locallogin = NULL ,   
    @useself = N'True' ;  
GO
```

Если авторизация SQL Server то просто создаем такой же логин на сязанном сервере.

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 
@rmtsrvname = N'SRVTEST\SQLTEST', -- имя должно быть таким же как в sp_addlinkedserver
@useself = N'False',
@rmtuser = 'MyUsername'
@rmtpassword = 'MyPassword';
```

Подробнее: [Создание связанных серверов (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017)